# Dynamically assign 'sticky' selected state for menu items that exchange iframe content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and couldn't find existing answers that solve/address my issue. 
My basic working setup is this:

Site has a menu on left side, corresponding page content is loaded into an iframe to the right. Clicking a menu-link exchanges the .htm displayed in the iframe, this is accomplished with javascript. Hover-effect for the links is a CSS background-color change to the transparent menu images.

These aspects ARE working ok! see relevant code parts:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_frame( srcURL ) {
        if ( !srcURL ) { return }
        var a_frame = document.getElementById('frame1');
        a_frame.src = srcURL;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu_lft">
    <div class="rollover"> 
        <a href="javascript:change_frame('media_nasd.htm')"><img src="img/cpf/clp_nas.gif" width="160" height="9" border="0" /><br /></a>
        <a href="javascript:change_frame('media_ibm.htm')"><img src="img/cpf/clp_ilm.gif" width="160" height="9" border="0" /><br /></a>
        <a href="javascript:change_frame('media_indo.htm')"><img src="img/cpf/clp_dgt.gif" width="160" height="9" border="0" /><br /></a>
        <a href="javascript:change_frame('media_att.htm')"><img src="img/cpf/clp_att.gif" width="160" height="9" border="0" /><br /></a>
        <a href="javascript:change_frame('media_the.htm')"><img src="img/cpf/clp_the.gif" width="160" height="9" border="0" /><br /></a>
        <a href="javascript:change_frame('media_ibs.htm')"><img src="img/cpf/clp_ibs.gif" width="160" height="9" border="0" /><br /></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">   
    <iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="600" id="frame1" name="frame1" src="media_nasd.htm"></iframe>  
</div>
</body>
```

Note: by default (i.e. when the main page is first accessed) the content for the top-most link is loaded into the iframe.

Now my QUESTION, how can I dynamically assign the "selected" state to the chosen menu item?

My classes for menu behavior:

```
    .rollover a { display:block; width:160px; height:9px; margin-bottom:4px; 
        background-color: #fff; 
    }
    .rollover a:hover { background-color: #dddedf; }    
    .rollsel { background-color: #fcc; }
```

What I mean: for the menu item that was clicked, which changed the content displayed in iframe, the class .rollsel or style="background-color: #fcc "  should display to indicate the correlation, i.e. 'stick' as long as related iframe content is being viewed.

It would seem this should be possible by extending/adding to the javascript... to dynamically insert the style change for the link used?

Yet I have NO CLUE how to go about it :( Can someone please advise - much appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about it is to creat an extra css class (ie: .rolloverselected or something similar) and use javascript to change the class of the selected item. The easiest way to go about it would probably be to use a js framework such as jQuery to simplify your code. Do keep in mind that, whenever you change the class of an element all the other must be "reset" to the default class.

Hope i gave you an idea of how to go about it :)